# Possibilities to hide Closed state workitems in TFS 2015 Backlogs

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 and working on Boards. I could perform show/hide Active and Resolved workitems from the options available in the top left corner of the window.

But is there a way to Hide Closed workitems from the lists ?[Screenshot listing closed items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxP0b.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But is there a way to Hide Closed workitems from the lists?

I am afraid there is no such way to Hide Closed workitems from the lists in the TFS 2015.

There is an implemented user voice about this request:

[Hide closed items option on all backlogs](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365562/hide-closed-items-in-backlog.html)

But this feature is deployed on the newer version of tfs, like: `TFS2018`. And it is not extended to the lower version of TFS. On the TFS 2018 and above, there is a filtering function in the upper right corner:

[image]

So there seems to be no such way to Hide Closed workitems from the lists in the TFS 2015 instead of updating TFS to 2018 and above.